# Qt queued connection of custom object leads to runtime error

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using Qt5.15.2.

I have a QObject used in my GUI and defined as below:

```
#pragma once

#include "actionstep.h"
#include "anotherthread.h"
#include <QTableWidget>

class TableWidget : public QTableWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TableWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QTableWidget(4, 4, parent) {

        int id = qRegisterMetaType<ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos>();
        std::cout << id << std::endl;

        connect(this, &TableWidget::SigUpdateActionStatusInfos, this,
                &TableWidget::SlotUpdateActionStatusInfos,
                Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection);

        th.start();
    }

    void methodCalledByAnotherThread(ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos ActionStepInfosObj)
    {
        emit SigUpdateActionStatusInfos(ActionStepInfosObj);
    }

signals:
    void SigUpdateActionStatusInfos(ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos as);

private slots:
    void SlotUpdateActionStatusInfos(ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos as) {
    }

private:
    AnotherThread th;
};
```

The idea is to be able to send my custom object of type `ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos` through the signal/slot service.

Content of `"actionstep.h"`, which contains my custom object:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <QMetaType>

class ActionStep {
public:

    class ActionStatusInfos {
    public:
        // Default constructor
        ActionStatusInfos() : Progress(0) {
        }

        // Default destructor
        ~ActionStatusInfos() = default;

        // Copy constructor
        ActionStatusInfos(ActionStatusInfos &source) {
            SetProgress(source.GetProgress());
        }

        // Copy assignment
        ActionStatusInfos &operator=(ActionStatusInfos &source) {
            SetProgress(source.GetProgress());
            return *this;
        }

        // move constructor
        ActionStatusInfos(ActionStatusInfos &&source) noexcept
        {
            SetProgress(source.GetProgress());
        }

        //move assignment
        ActionStatusInfos &operator=(ActionStatusInfos &&source) noexcept
        {
            SetProgress(source.GetProgress());
            return *this;
        }

        void SetProgress(int pg) {
            Progress = pg;
        }

        int GetProgress() {
            return Progress;
        }

    private:
        int Progress;
    };

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos)
```

I've added both `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos)` and `qRegisterMetaType<ActionStep::ActionStatusInfos>()`, and my class seems to meet the minimum requirements needed by Qt for registering a custom class (default ctor, dtor and copy ctor).

At runtime, `methodCalledByAnotherThread` is called by a different thread than the GUI. After a few cycles, I get a SIGFAULT, and the debugger shows that there is a dangling reference when the Qt stuff is executed.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This isn't the solution to your problem, but as a side note, the argument to your copy-constructor and copy-assignment-operator should be `const ActionStatusInfos &`, not just `ActionStatusInfos &` (and also `int GetProgress()` should be `int GetProgress() const`)

Comment: I ran your code with Qt 5.15.2 on Suse Linux 15.1. It would not compile because Qt MetaObject complains about constness just like @JeremyFriesner. After fixing that it run smoothly without crash. As second thread I used std::async and called the method. Seems like your example does not include your error.

Comment: You state `"At runtime, methodCalledByAnotherThread is called by a different thread than the GUI"`.  You need to show the code that manages the thread and performs that call.  If you're accessing data concurrently from multiple threads without any form of synchronization (mutex etc.) you've probably got undefined behaviour.

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to call methods from another thread, move your signal to `AnotherThread` and emit it from there.

Comment: I would suggest that you first start passing just ordinary `int` as the progress. If this fails, then you will know that the problem is elsewhere in your code. If it works with plain `int` then your problem is obviously with your class `ActionStatusInfos`. Btw. I do not think you really need to define all that destructors, copy and move constructors and assigment operators.